# Commutation relation of Hamiltonian and Del operator

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, hamiltonian

Let we have a crystalline solid whose Hamiltonian is given as (equ.1):
$$H=\frac{p^2}{2m}+V$$
where $V$ is periodic which means eigenfunctions are Blochstates $\psi_{nk}$ with eigenvalues $E_{nk}$. One can write Schrodinger equation as $H|\psi_{nk}>=E_{nk}|\psi_{nk}>$ or equivalently $H|u_{nk}>=E_{nk}|u_{nk}>$ where $|u_{nk}>$ is cell periodic function and (equ.2)
$$H=\frac{(p^2+\hbar k)^2}{2m}+V$$

In this article

> Theory of polarization of crystalline solids, R.D. King-Smith and David Vanderbilt, [Phys. Rev. B 47, 1651(R), 1993](https://journals.aps.org/prb/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevB.47.1651).

authors wrote a equations which I want to understand (equ. 3)
$$<\psi_{nk}|p|\psi_{mk}>=\frac{m}{\hbar}<u_{nk}|[\partial_k,H]|u_{mk}>$$
in these equations $H$ is given by equ.2

**My attempt:**

write right hand side of equ.3 as:
$$<\psi_{nk}|p|\psi_{mk}>=\frac{m}{\hbar}<\psi_{nk}|[\partial_k,H]|\psi_{mk}>$$
now $H$ is given by equ.1. Right hand side of above equation is (using $p=\hbar k$)
$$=\frac{m}{\hbar}[<\psi_{nk}|\partial_kH|\psi_{mk}>-<\psi_{nk}|H\partial_k|\psi_{mk}>]$$
$$=\frac{m}{\hbar}[\frac{2\hbar}{2m}<\psi_{nk}|p|\psi_{mk}>-<\psi_{nk}|H\partial_k|\psi_{mk}>]$$
$$=<\psi_{nk}|p|\psi_{mk}>-\frac{m}{\hbar}<\psi_{nk}|H\partial_k|\psi_{mk}>$$
First term is exactly what I wanted but how to deal with second term? It should be zero. How?

Comment: Hint: what does the partial derivative act on?

Comment: It's acting on eigenstate which doesn't change so this derivative will be zero. am I correct?

Comment: I'm concerned with the first term on the first line of your derivation

Comment: OMG. I am so stupid. I am missing a term $+<\psi_{nk}|H\partial_k |\psi_{mk}>$ which will be cancelled with last term.
Thank you so so much.

Comment: No worries! It's easy to forget

Comment: Can you explain where that missing term comes from?

Comment: @BillyKalfus First equation term in my attempt can be written as: $<\psi_{nk}|\partial_k( H |\psi_{nk}>)=<\psi_{nk}|[(\partial_k H)|\psi_{nk}>+H\partial_k|\psi_{nk}>]=2\hbar/2m<\psi_{nk}|p|\psi_{nk}>+<\psi_{nk}|H\partial_k|\psi_{nk}>$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First equation term in my attempt can be written as: $<\psi_{nk}|\partial_k( H |\psi_{nk}>)=<\psi_{nk}|[(\partial_k H)|\psi_{nk}>+H\partial_k|\psi_{nk}>]=2\hbar/2m<\psi_{nk}|p|\psi_{nk}>+<\psi_{nk}|H\partial_k|\psi_{nk}>$